# Connected components of $Q(\mathrm{s\tau-tilt}A)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, quivers

I'm reading about support $\tau$-tilting modules and their mutations. I'm trying to understand the mutation quiver.

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field, which is $\tau$-tilting infinite. Let $Q(\mathrm{s\tau-tilt} A)$ be the mutation quiver of all the basic support $\tau$-tilting modules of $A$. I have found examples where $Q(\mathrm{s\tau-tilt} A)$ has two connected components (one component is given by left mutations starting from $A$ and the other component is given by the right mutations starting from $0$).

> For a $\tau$-tilting infinite algebra, is it known when $Q(\mathrm{s\tau-tilt} A)$ is not connected? How many connected components it has?

> I'm wondering if this $Q(\mathrm{s\tau-tilt} A)$ can have $3$ or more connected components?

> If yes, then what is the "starting" module in these connected components (other than the ones that I've described above)?

> What is an example of a $\tau$-tilting infinite algebra $A$ where $Q(\mathrm{s\tau-tilt} A)$ has $3$ or more connected components?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4709602/884739